# Assign different windows of same application to different spaces (macOS 12 monterey)

Tags: spaces

I have the same question as per this question [Assign Application Windows to Different Spaces/Desktops](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/105463/21537) but i hope my question doesn't get closed for duplicate.

The reason is I am asking for more than just Safari windows.

Like the original question i want to have different windows of the same app appear in different spaces even upon rebooting of my macbook pro.

I am running macOS 12.1 mbp 2021 model with Apple Silicon.

There's an answer that appears to use bundle identifier. Not sure how that works exactly.

The apps that have multiple windows i hope to spread across different spaces are:

1. ms edge (my default browser)
2. vscode (my default code editor)
3. terminal
4. stickies (because i want to use [that](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/345228/21537) to identify/rename my spaces easily)

Comment: "There's an answer that appears to use bundle identifier. Not sure how that works exactly." what exactly don't you understand? What happened when you tried it?

Comment: that solution appears targeted to safari only. not sure if it also works for terminal and vscode. Also it appears i need to do the bundle idenfitier everytime i have a new Space. It seems more intrusive than i would like

Comment: You need to make the app recognise each new copy as a new process. Basically, you're trying to fight the system. Expect some kick-back. Spaces was designed to assign an app to a Space, not a window to a Space.